# Stored procedure for inserting a constant plus values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to modify the following stored procedure if we want in the inserted records the `Col3` contain a constant string 'Foo'?

```
INSERT Table2
       (Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3)
SELECT T1Col1,
       T1Col2
FROM   Table1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT Table2
       (Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3)
SELECT T1Col1,
       T1Col2,
       'Something'
FROM   Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT Table2
       (Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3)
SELECT T1Col1,
       T1Col2,
       'Foo'
FROM   Table1
```

Comment: Thank you! Marked Paddy's answer as accepted. He was 30 secons earlier :) +1