# insert into select from sql query with both query and static values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to perform insert query from one specific column from a table plus two static values, I am trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(PolicyId, Type, Used)
SELECT ID FROM Policies, 'A', 1
```

But I am getting error near 'A' per SSMSE. 
Any idea how can I tackle this task? 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored procedure for inserting a constant plus values from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133610/stored-procedure-for-inserting-a-constant-plus-values-from-another-table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to put these static values in your `SELECT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(PolicyId, Type, Used) SELECT ID, 'A', 1 FROM Policies
```

Comment: Thanks that was easy, I'll accept your answer as correct in 10 minutes. Have a nice day