# SQL select only specific fields and insert them in another table + static values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I would like to insert data from specific fields from one table in another table + some static values. Roughly I would like to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(Field1, Field2, Field3) 
SELECT Field1, Field2, 'staticvalue', Field3
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.Field6 = 'XYZ'
```

Any idea how can I mix both specific fields from one table and static values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored procedure for inserting a constant plus values from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133610/stored-procedure-for-inserting-a-constant-plus-values-from-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track... you need to supply a column for the static value to be inserted into.

```
INSERT INTO TableA(Field1, Field2, someOtherField, Field3) 
SELECT Field1, Field2, 'staticvalue', Field3
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.Field6 = 'XYZ'
```